# Javascript - how to create a form element and submit?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I need to redirect to a different page when a JS process instantiated on the current one is complete. Problem is only JS knows when it is complete, and I'm using Python (Flask) as the web framework. I thought of creating a form element sort of like a "submit" button(which the Python app can listen for) and just sending that upon completion How can I go about this, or is there a better way?(I'm assuming it requires some jQuery magic)

Comment: Do you need POST request or GET is fine?

Comment: then you can just change location: `location = "script.py"`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com");
```

or this:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery,

```
var url = '/..url to post..', dataMap = {
    a : 1,
    b : 2
};

//create a form
var $form = $('<form>').appendTo(document.body);

//set action, target, method
$form.attr({
    action : url,
    target : '_blank',
    method : 'POST'
});

//create inputs,
for ( var k in dataMap) {
    $('<input type="hidden" />').attr('name', k).val(dataMap[k]).appendTo($form);
}

$form.submit();
$form.remove();
```